# How can i extract image from button icon in PDF using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to get image icon from button in pdf using java netbeans, and put it in some panel.
However i hit a brick here.
I'm using PDFBox as my PDF exporter, and i can't seem to understand enough. 
I already succeed reading from the form field, but there is no button extractor as long as i try to find it in PDFBox.
How should i made it ? And is it possible using this method, or is there any other way around.
Thanks in advance.

Edit : 
I already found to extractimages using the one that are in example utility using this code :

```
       File myFile = new File(filename);
        try { 

            //PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq( myFile, null );
            PDDocument pdDoc = null;
            pdDoc = PDDocument.load( myFile );
            PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();
            // dipakai untuk membaca isi file

            List pages = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
             while( iter.hasNext() )
             {
                 PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
                 PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                 Map images = resources.getImages();
                 if( images != null )
                 {
                     Iterator imageIter = images.keySet().iterator();
                     while( imageIter.hasNext() )
                     {
                         String key = (String  )imageIter.next();
                         PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)images.get(key);
                         BufferedImage imagedisplay= image.getRGBImage();
                         jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imagedisplay)); // NOI18N                                 
                     }
                 }
             }


        } catch (Exception e) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error " + e.getMessage());


        }
```

However i still fail reading from the button images.
Btw i read the tutorial from this page to add button images to pdf.
https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-button-form-field-to-insert-a-pdf-file

 
2nd Edit : 
Here i also give you the link to the pdf that has icon in it. [PDF Link](http://www.docdroid.net/TDGVQzg/imageicon.pdf.html).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a one time only thing? Please upload the PDF somewhere.

Comment: No, i'm using it for application so i will use it many times. I already read to made all page into image and then extract it, however i'm still trying to implement it. Thank you for your quick answer

Comment: There is an ExtractImages example utility in the PDFBox source code that you could try. If that isn't successful, you should use PDFDebugger command utility to find out where that "button" is (likely in the Acroform part). Use the 2.0 version of PDFDebugger. https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-debugger/

Comment: Thank you. I will try to read it, and will post here if i get the answer.

Comment: Your code looks at the page content image resources; buttons, though, are not part of the content but have their own resources. Can you share a sample file containing such an image button for analysis?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean interactive form buttons when you talk about *buttons in PDFs*.

### In general

There is no explicit icon extractor for buttons in PDFBox. But as buttons (and annotations in general) with custom icons have these icons defined as part of their appearances, one can simply (recursively) traverse the resources of the appearances of the annotations and collect the **XObject**s with subtype **Image**:

```
public void extractAnnotationImages(PDDocument document, String fileNameFormat) throws IOException
{
    List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    if (pages == null)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++)
    {
        String pageFormat = String.format(fileNameFormat, "-" + i + "%s", "%s");
        extractAnnotationImages(pages.get(i), pageFormat);
    }
}

public void extractAnnotationImages(PDPage page, String pageFormat) throws IOException
{
    List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
    if (annotations == null)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < annotations.size(); i++)
    {
        PDAnnotation annotation = annotations.get(i);
        String annotationFormat = annotation.getAnnotationName() != null && annotation.getAnnotationName().length() > 0
                ? String.format(pageFormat, "-" + annotation.getAnnotationName() + "%s", "%s")
                : String.format(pageFormat, "-" + i + "%s", "%s");
        extractAnnotationImages(annotation, annotationFormat);
    }
}

public void extractAnnotationImages(PDAnnotation annotation, String annotationFormat) throws IOException
{
    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = annotation.getAppearance();
    extractAnnotationImages(appearance.getDownAppearance(), String.format(annotationFormat, "-Down%s", "%s"));
    extractAnnotationImages(appearance.getNormalAppearance(), String.format(annotationFormat, "-Normal%s", "%s"));
    extractAnnotationImages(appearance.getRolloverAppearance(), String.format(annotationFormat, "-Rollover%s", "%s"));
}

public void extractAnnotationImages(Map<String, PDAppearanceStream> stateAppearances, String stateFormat) throws IOException
{
    if (stateAppearances == null)
        return;

    for (Map.Entry<String, PDAppearanceStream> entry: stateAppearances.entrySet())
    {
        String appearanceFormat = String.format(stateFormat, "-" + entry.getKey() + "%s", "%s");
        extractAnnotationImages(entry.getValue(), appearanceFormat);
    }
}

public void extractAnnotationImages(PDAppearanceStream appearance, String appearanceFormat) throws IOException
{
    PDResources resources = appearance.getResources();
    if (resources == null)
        return;
    Map<String, PDXObject> xObjects = resources.getXObjects();
    if (xObjects == null)
        return;

    for (Map.Entry<String, PDXObject> entry : xObjects.entrySet())
    {
        PDXObject xObject = entry.getValue();
        String xObjectFormat = String.format(appearanceFormat, "-" + entry.getKey() + "%s", "%s");
        if (xObject instanceof PDXObjectForm)
            extractAnnotationImages((PDXObjectForm)xObject, xObjectFormat);
        else if (xObject instanceof PDXObjectImage)
            extractAnnotationImages((PDXObjectImage)xObject, xObjectFormat);
    }
}

public void extractAnnotationImages(PDXObjectForm form, String imageFormat) throws IOException
{
    PDResources resources = form.getResources();
    if (resources == null)
        return;
    Map<String, PDXObject> xObjects = resources.getXObjects();
    if (xObjects == null)
        return;

    for (Map.Entry<String, PDXObject> entry : xObjects.entrySet())
    {
        PDXObject xObject = entry.getValue();
        String xObjectFormat = String.format(imageFormat, "-" + entry.getKey() + "%s", "%s");
        if (xObject instanceof PDXObjectForm)
            extractAnnotationImages((PDXObjectForm)xObject, xObjectFormat);
        else if (xObject instanceof PDXObjectImage)
            extractAnnotationImages((PDXObjectImage)xObject, xObjectFormat);
    }
}

public void extractAnnotationImages(PDXObjectImage image, String imageFormat) throws IOException
{
    image.write2OutputStream(new FileOutputStream(String.format(imageFormat, "", image.getSuffix())));
}
```

*(from [ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java))*

Unfortunately the OP did not provide a sample PDF so I applied the code to [this example file](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter08/buttons.pdf)

[image: buttons.pdf screenshot]

(stored as a resource) like this:

```
/**
 * Test using <a href="http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter08/buttons.pdf">buttons.pdf</a>
 * created by <a href="http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=154">part2.chapter08.Buttons</a>
 * from ITEXT IN ACTION — SECOND EDITION.
 */
@Test
public void testButtonsPdf() throws IOException
{
    try (InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("buttons.pdf"))
    {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
        extractAnnotationImages(document, new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "buttons%s.%s").toString());;
    }
}
```

*(from [ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java))*

and got these images:

[image: buttons-0-10-Normal-default-FRM-img0.png]

and

[image: buttons-0-10-Normal-default-FRM-img1.png]

There are two issues here:

- We extract *all image resources* attached to the annotation appearance and do not check whether they actually are *used* anywhere in the appearance stream. Thus, you might find more icons than expected. In the case above, the first image is not used as individual resource but only as mask for the second one.
- We extract *only image resources*, not inline images, and so may miss some images.

Thus, please check this code with your PDFs. If need be, it can be improved.

### The OP's file

The OP meanwhile has provided a sample file [imageicon.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/imageicon.pdf)

[image: imageicon.pdf screenshot]

Calling the methods above like this

```
/**
 * Test using <a href="http://www.docdroid.net/TDGVQzg/imageicon.pdf.html">imageicon.pdf</a>
 * created by the OP.
 */
@Test
public void testImageiconPdf() throws IOException
{
    try (InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageicon.pdf"))
    {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
        extractAnnotationImages(document, new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "imageicon%s.%s").toString());;
    }
}
```

*(from [ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java))*

outputs this image:

[image: imageicon-0-0-Normal-default-FRM-NxIm0.jpg]

Thus, it works just fine!

### Starting as stand alone tool

The OP indicated in a comment to be

> still confuse using junit testing method, however when i try to call it into my main program, it always return with "stream close" error. I already put the file as the same directory as my jar, also trying to give the path manually, but still the same error.

Thus, I added a `main` method to the class to allow it to

1. be started without the JUnit framework and
2. extract from PDFs anywhere in the local file system given by their file names on the command line.

In code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ExtractAnnotationImageTest extractor = new ExtractAnnotationImageTest();

    for (String arg : args)
    {
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(arg))
        {
            extractor.extractAnnotationImages(document, arg+"%s.%s");;
        }
    }
}
```

*(from [ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractAnnotationImageTest.java))*

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and fast answer. I already tried your code, however it was return with an error. it says Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type : (any). I don't really understand what is happening. I also upload the pdf that i try to extract in this link [link](http://www.docdroid.net/TDGVQzg/imageicon.pdf.html). Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type : (any)* - that does not sound like a java compile error message at all... Have you used the github copy of the java file or did you copy&paste from the answer?

Comment: To @mkl : I already getting from the github copy, but i'm still confuse using junit testing method, however when i try to call it into my main program, it always return with "stream close" error. I already put the file as the same directory as my jar, also trying to give the path manually, but still the same error. I know you already help me so much in this, and it is because of my lacked programming skills, but can you give me a code snippet so i can call the extract method into my main program without any errors?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a `main` method to allow the class to be used as a stand-alone tool which processes PDFs given by their file names on the command line.

Comment: Thank you, you are such a great person. Anyway, sometimes when the image is not yet uploaded it will return error as null pointer exception, and there is one line of code that i add to help prevent the error, that is         if (appearance == null) return; in line 149. I hope it helps for anyone reading this problem. Thank you very much @mkl. Two thumbs up for you.