# Adding image to existing button in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox 2.x to fill out forms. This worked great so far but now I've come up to a form that requires 2 images (seal and signature) to be added in image/button placeholders/fields. I've been looking for a solution for this but no luck so far.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958843/how-to-import-an-icon-to-a-button-field-in-a-pdf-using-pdfbox) is the closest thing I've found to the problem I have but I can't make it work with existing buttons.

Does anyone have a hint how to solve this?